# Defining a function inside a for

Tags: javascript, scope

I need to do several GET requests, and I need to define the callback function differently each time. I am doing this with a for, like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    let url = "http...";
    httpGetAsync(url, function (responseText) {
        // do things with j
    });
}
```

But when it gets to the "do things with j" line j is always n, i.e. the value it has on the last iteration of the loop. I guess the callback functions are running after the loop has completed all its iterations, and they take the j that there is at that time.

But why is that? Shouldn't the callback function be defined using a different j each time? Shouldn't the functions use the value for j from when they were defined?

Do I need to put the callback function into a closure?

I'm pretty sure it's a matter of keeping track of the scope, but if you need the httpGetAsync function it looks like this:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: `let j = 0; j < n; j++`

Comment: Yep, that works. I still have to figure why, but it works.

As for the duplicate, my apologies, I did search but somehow I missed that one. Thanks for everything.

Comment: It's part of the `let` magic. It creates a new, different binding in each iteration.

Comment: `httpGetAsync(url, function(responseText){/* do things with j*/ }.bind(this, j);`

Comment: `[...new Array(n).keys()].forEach(j=>httpGetAsync(url, function(responseText){/* do things with j*/});`